# material design getting started example fails on npm start

Tags: webpack, sass, material-design

I am following the material design get started guide:

https://material.io/develop/web/getting-started

I am literally copying and pasting the code and following strictly the guide. However, when I want to start the app using npm start, webpack successfully starts but the browser returns a cannot get error. In the console, I have a 404 not found error.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to webpack. (I assume there is something wrong in the webpack.config.js)